# How to exclude properties after Include() usage for filtering

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In order to filter a list of items, I'm using the type of a related property like this.

```
var list = Context.Items
    .Include(_ => _.Details)
    .Where(_ => _.Details.Kind == kind));

return list;
```

This returns the full listing filtered by *kind*, which in this case is rather bad as the *Details* property is large, duplicated precisely in each returned element (no two details of the same kind can ever differ) and the list of items might be quite long.

So, while using *kind* in *Details* to filter out the correct subset of items, I want the field to be empty upon returning it. One way to solve it is to obtain the IDs of all the items and then select based on that. Seems inefficient and slow. Another way is to migrate a guid into the class *Item* and use that for filtration. That appears duplicative and intrusive for the data model.

Is there a neat way to drop the included properties?

I'm thinking about an equivalent to the following (not working, immaginative) sample.

```
var list = Context.Items
    .Include(_ => _.Details)
    .Where(_ => _.Details.Kind == kind));

return list.Forget(_ => _.Details);
```

Comment: You don't need the include if your accessing the navigational property inside the query itself. The include is only necessary if you want the data in your end result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Include` is only needed when you want that navigational property's data to be, well, *included*, in the result.

Operations translated to SQL, like `GroupBy` and `Where`, do not need the use of `Include`, so you can just do:

```
var list = Context.Items.Where(_ => _.Details.Kind == kind));
```

Another common error (as far as I have seen), is using `Include` with `Select`. When you use `Select`, all `Include`s are effectively thrown away.